# Topological Manifold which does not admit Riemann surface structure?

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, riemann-surfaces

I have a question motivated by some examples in section 4.2 of Schlag's *A Course in Complex Analysis and Riemann Surfaces*.

Example 1. Any smooth, orientable two-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a Riemann surface

Example 2. Any polyhedral surface $S ⊂ \mathbb{R}^3$ is a Riemann surface.

The first statement says that all smooth orientable surfaces are Riemann surfaces. The second suggests that the converse to the first statement is false.

My question is then:

- Do all orientable topological manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ admit a Riemann surface structure?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say a topological manifold _is_ a Riemann surface.  Rather, you should say it admits a Riemann surface structure.  Also, presumably you mean to restrict to manifolds of dimension 2?

Comment: The word "are: in the first question is quite slippery here as noted in the other comment; what does it mean exactly? in other words, what is the isomorphism class of the manifold in question because up to homeomorphism all (orientable) 2-dimensional topological manifolds are smooth, but obviously, they have non-smooth (eg with corners) embeddings in Euclidean $3d$ space like in example $2$; so the question is very imprecise as it stands

Comment: The orientability assumption in Example 1 is necessary, so it should also be included in your question.

Comment: You have to assume that your submanifold in $R^3$ is 2-dimensional. Once you have this, then it is an orientable topological surface and, hence, admits a Riemann surface structure: Embedding in $R^3$ is totally irrelevant.